# How to do such a split for dict when values in dict is a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict, where key is string, value is a list containing some numbers, such as d in code.
I want to return a list where each element is a dict containing all the keys in the input dict and containing value in increasing order, such as result in code.
Suppose we don't know how many elements in a list(may not be 3 or 4 in code),but the number of elements are the same.

e.g. 1:

```py
d = {'1': [11, 12, 13], '2': [21, 22, 23], '3': [31, 32, 33]}
# ???
result = [{'1': 11, '2': 21, '3': 31},
          {'1': 12, '2': 22, '3': 23},
          {'1': 13, '2': 23, '3': 33}]
```

e.g. 2:

```py
d = {'1': [11, 12, 13, 14], '2': [21, 22, 23, 24], '3': [31, 32, 33, 34]}
# ???
result = [{'1': 11, '2': 21, '3': 31},
          {'1': 12, '2': 22, '3': 23},
          {'1': 13, '2': 23, '3': 33},
          {'1': 14, '2': 24, '3': 34}, ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are the lists in the original dict guaranteed to be in increasing order? (because you didn't state they are, but both your examples respect this precondition).

Comment: Edit: what "increasing" means it that keeping the original order in the list, not something like numerically increasing.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` all the values lists together, then zip each resulting `tuple` of values with the keys to make the new `dict`s:

```
result = [dict(zip(d, vs)) for vs in zip(*d.values())]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pc7BCgIhEAbgu08xNzVkQcdT0JMsHiKLhFJxbaGiZ7exvXrr8DPDd5j587NeU8QW7jmVCjmXEGvzcIA313wPs9YKtKGgU8BNJ0NkiMyPsBMSIRGi@7DtyLQNMftwquIVsvAK1kVKuKRCC4QIXXd@Wo@3x3kRUjrJ2PA3xQ7@U@ygA8X@26O1Lw)

This works because the iteration order of a `dict` is consistent with the iteration order of its values (it's insertion ordered in 3.6+, but it's consistent for a given run of Python for all versions); the keys from `d` in the "every loop" `zip` will be iterated in the same order the values were pulled in the up front `zip`.

This assumes that by "increasing order" you mean "preserves the ordering of the input"; if that's not the case, judicious use of the `sorted` built-in would be necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of values is sorted, the following code works fine to get your desired output.

```
def answer(testdict):
    result = []
    lengths = [len(v) for v in testdict.values()]
    length = lengths[0]
    for i in range(length):
        newdict = {}
        for j in testdict:
            newdict[j] = testdict[j][i]
        result.append(newdict)
    print(result)
```

However, if the list of values isn't sorted, try using `sorted` first.

Comment: I prefer to use a no-loop implementation, but still thanks a lot.